# How to retrieve Rocket Core module parameters from Top module in fpga-zynq repository

Tags: scala, io, hierarchy, chisel

My goal is to **add counters** to the [rocket class](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/rocket/rocket.scala) of the **Rocket Core module** of the [fpga-zynq repository](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq). I want to count parameters like *ctrl_stalld, id_stall_fpu* ... while the chip is **running on a FPGA**.

I successfully generated Verilog code and a Vivado project for the default rocket configuration (ZynqConfig). I loaded it onto the ZedBoard's FPGA and got it running. **I know how to implement counters in the core**, but i'm not sure how to **retrieve them from outside**.

I figured, that a connection between *fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocket/**rocket.scala*** and *fpga-zynq/common/src/main/scala/**Top.scala*** probably has to be established, since i'm able to access and further connect the Top modules IO-Ports inside Xilinx Vivado 2016.2. I'd assume that the projects hierarchy has to be backtraced from **rocket module** to **Top module** and all IO-Ports of all modules in between connected.

However, i do **not** **quite** **understand the projects hierarchy**. I can't find a connection over the many many modules between **rocket** and **Top**. I hope the image clarifies what i' trying to say.

[image: NOT an actual representation of the fpga-zynq projects hierarchy]
The arrows represent IO connections between modules.

The black dots and "?" represent unknown hierarchy (may be more complex).

This is **NOT** an actual representation of the fpga-zynq projects hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As predicted, all the I/O Ports of all the modules between **Top** and **rocket** had to be connected.
**NOTE**: The following solution is meant to work only for a **Single Core Rocket**!

I'm gonna go through the steps necessary to implement a 32-bit counter in the Rocket core and connecting it with the Top module.

**Where to find the following classes:**

**Rocket** -- *fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocket/rocket.scala*

**RocketTile** -- *fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocket/tile.scala*

**BaseCorePlexModule** -- *fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/src/main/scala/coreplex/BaseCoreplexModule.scala*

**BaseTop** -- *fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocketchip/BaseTop.scala*

**Top** -- *fpga-zynq/common/src/main/scala/Top.scala*

## 1. Implementing a counter in the Rocket class

First, we **create a new Bundle** for all our counters, outside the Rocket class
*(for this example, it will be just one counter, but you can add more counters and other parameters to the bundle as you go)*

```
class CounterBundle extends Bundle{
   val counter = UInt(OUTPUT, width = 32)
}
```

We define an **instance of this Bundle** in the **I/O** Bundle of the **Rocket class**.

```
class Rocket(implicit p: Parameters) extends CoreModule()(p) {
    val io = new Bundle {
      val interrupts = new TileInterrupts().asInput
      val hartid = UInt(INPUT, xLen)
      val imem = new FrontendIO()(p.alterPartial({ case CacheName => "L1I" }))
      val dmem = new HellaCacheIO()(p.alterPartial({ case CacheName => "L1D" }))
      val ptw = new DatapathPTWIO().flip
      val fpu = new FPUIO().flip
      val rocc = new RoCCInterface().flip
      val cBundle = new CounterBundle
    }
// ...
}
```

Since our "counter" parameter is essentially a wire and we can't assign a wire to itself, we'll use a **register to count** and **transfer its value to our counter**. The counter will be **incremented** if some condition is true and **reset** back to 0 if reset is active. We put it inside the Rocket class.

```
val counter_reg = Reg(init = UInt(0, width = 32))
when(/*some condition*/){
  counter_reg := counter_reg + 1.U
}
io.cBundle.counter := counter_reg
```

That's it for the Rocket class.

## 2. Connecting the Rocket class CounterBundle with the Top class

### 2.1 Rocket → RocketTile

A new **Rocket** class **instance** is created in the **RocketTile** class.

Simply add

```
val cBundle = new CounterBundle
```

to the RocketTile I/O's.
Now let's go ahead and **connect the two bundles** inside the RocketTile class.

```
class RocketTile(clockSignal: Clock = null, resetSignal: Bool = null)
(implicit p: Parameters) extends Tile(clockSignal, resetSignal)(p) {
  val buildRocc = p(BuildRoCC)
  val usingRocc = !buildRocc.isEmpty
  val nRocc = buildRocc.size
  val nFPUPorts = buildRocc.filter(_.useFPU).size

  val core = Module(new Rocket)
  io.cBundle := core.io.cBundle
  // ...
}
```

If you're wondering where the **RocketTile I/O's** are defined, look for the **TileIO** class within the same file (tile.scala).

### 2.2 RocketTile → BaseCorePlexModule

The BaseCorePlexModule holds a **set of tiles**. But since we are only creating a counter for a **single core rocket**, we can just **connect the Bundle of the first RocketTile in the set**.

First, add

```
val cBundle = new CounterBundle
```

to the **"abstract class BaseCoreplexBundle"** right above the BaseCorePlexModule. As you probably figured, the BaseCorePlexBundle holds all the I/O's for the BaseCorePlexModule.

Then, **connect** this Bundle with the **RocketTile** Bundle inside the **BaseCorePlexModule**.

```
abstract class BaseCoreplexModule[+L <: BaseCoreplex, +B <: BaseCoreplexBundle](
c: CoreplexConfig, l: L, b: => B)(implicit val p: Parameters) extends LazyModuleImp(l) with HasCoreplexParameters {
   val outer: L = l
   val io: B = b

   // Build a set of Tiles
   val tiles = p(BuildTiles) map { _(reset, p) }
   io.cBundle := tiles.head.io.cBundle
   // ...
 }
```

### 2.3 BaseCorePlexModule → BaseTop

This is the **last connection** to be made before going to the **Top class**, as the Top class holds a parameter **"target"** that is a **child of BaseTop**.

Again, add a **new instance of the CounterBundle** to the I/O's of this class. The **"abstract class BaseTopBundle"** holds all the **I/O's** for BaseTop.

Connect the two.

```
abstract class BaseTopModule[+L <: BaseTop, +B <: BaseTopBundle](
val p: Parameters, l: L, b: => B) extends LazyModuleImp(l) {
  val outer: L = l
  val io: B = b

  val coreplex = p(BuildCoreplex)(outer.c, p)
  io.cBundle := coreplex.io.cBundle
  // ... 
}
```

### 2.4 BaseTop → Top

The Top class holds a parameter **"target"** of type **FPGAZynqTop**

```
val target = LazyModule(new FPGAZynqTop(p)).module
```

At the bottom of the file, FPGAZynqTop can be found as a **child of BaseTop**. Therefore, we can access the BaseTop I/O's through the "target" parameter.

For the Top I/O, we are not going to add the CounterBundle, but the 32-bit "counter" parameter from the Bundle. This way, the counter can be accessed in Vivado, as the generated Verilog code will hold a 32-bit wire.

Adding the a **32-bit UInt parameter** to the Top I/O

```
val counter = UInt(OUTPUT, width = 32)
```

Connecting it with the counter from the CounterBundle.

```
class Top(implicit val p: Parameters) extends Module {
   val io = new Bundle {
     val ps_axi_slave = new NastiIO()(AdapterParams(p)).flip
     val mem_axi = new NastiIO
     val counter = UInt(OUTPUT, width = 32)
   }

   val target = LazyModule(new FPGAZynqTop(p)).module
   val slave = Module(new ZynqAXISlave(1)(AdapterParams(p)))
   io.counter := target.io.cBundle.counter
   // ...
}
```

## Conclusion

Counting Rocket Core parameters while the chip runs on a FPGA is possible with this configuration. I tested it on a ZedBoard.

With this setup you can simply add more counters / parameters to the CounterBundle without having to go through all the modules between Rocket and Top again. Of course, you will still have to also alter the Top module.

## EDIT

After adding more and more parameter to the Bundle, i realised that also adding all of these to the Top module every time becomes annoying. You can **add the CounterBundle directly to the Top module I/O**. In the generated Verilog code,  the CounterBundle will be extracted into all it's containing signals.

My new Top module looks like this. *Be sure to import the CounterBundle from the Rocket class*

```
import rocket.CounterBundle

class Top(implicit val p: Parameters) extends Module {
   val io = new Bundle {
     val ps_axi_slave = new NastiIO()(AdapterParams(p)).flip
     val mem_axi = new NastiIO
     val cBundle = new CounterBundle
   }

   val target = LazyModule(new FPGAZynqTop(p)).module
   val slave = Module(new ZynqAXISlave(1)(AdapterParams(p)))
   io.cBundle := target.io.cBundle
   // ...
}
```

The passage in the generated Verilog code for the Top module then looks like this.

```
module Top(
  input clock,
  input reset,
  // ...
  output [31:0] io_cBundle_counter
);
// ...
endmodule
```